# My app is being tested on iPad although it's developed for iPhone

Tags: ipad, ios5, crash, crash-reports

My app was rejected but I don't know what's the exact problem.

Rejected reason is:

> We found that your app crashed on iPad 3rd Gen. running iOS 5.1.1,
>   which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> Your app crashed on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks when we select an
>   item from the table view.

However I submitted my application for iPhones only. On top of that I couldn't figure out what's wrong in the crash files and could not debug as I tested it on my iPhone and I didn't have any bugs or crashes.

Any help or tip will be extremely appreciated as I feel totally lost in this one. Million thanks in advance.

You can find the crash reports below..

```
Incident Identifier: 5E4A2B4C-EC76-441B-82A2-3782F53B533B
CrashReporter Key:   5ee8aa21dffe8c0b7f3386a5290b271457c404c8
Hardware Model:      iPad3,3
Process:         *****
Path:            *****
Identifier:      *****
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-06-04 18:44:59.930 -0700
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1.1 (9B206)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 
'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target <ViewController: 
0x176f80>.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x3309e88f 0x35043259 0x35687441 00x356e26a7 0x84d9f 0x3565793d 0x356d1627 0x3777d933 
0x33072a33 0x33072699 0x3307126f 0x32ff44a5 0x32ff436d 0x33141439 0x355d3cd5 0x83f03 
0x83ec4)


Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x3309e88f 0x35043259 0x35687441 0x356e26a7 0x84d9f 0x3565793d 0x356d1627 0x3777d933 
0x33072a33 0x33072699 0x3307126f 0x32ff44a5 0x32ff436d 0x33141439 0x355d3cd5 0x83f03 
0x83ec4)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3557532c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3249b208 pthread_kill + 48
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32494298 abort + 88
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x34219f64 abort_message + 40
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x34217346 _ZL17default_terminatev + 18
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x35043350 _objc_terminate + 140
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x342173be _ZL19safe_handler_callerPFvvE + 70
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3421744a std::terminate() + 14
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3421881e __cxa_rethrow + 82
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x350432a2 objc_exception_rethrow + 6
10  CoreFoundation                  0x32ff4506 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 398
11  CoreFoundation                  0x32ff4366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
12  GraphicsServices                0x33141432 GSEventRunModal + 130
13  UIKit                           0x355d3cce UIApplicationMain + 1074
14  ******                  0x00083efc 0x82000 + 7932
15  ******                  0x00083ebc 0x82000 + 7868

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x355653a8 kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x317c9f04 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 708
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x317c9c22 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 30

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35575cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32456f36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32456cc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3 name:  WebThread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35565004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x355651fa mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x330723ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x33071124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x32ff449e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x32ff4366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   WebCore                         0x35d92c9c _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 396
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3245c72e _pthread_start + 314
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3245c5e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35575cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32456f36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32456cc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35575cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32456f36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32456cc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6:
0   AddressBook                     0x338c7cc8 ABAddressBookCreate + 0
1   TextInput                       0x345d11be
KB::fill_with_matchable_strings_from_address_book(KB::Hashmap<KB::String, bool>&) + 10
2   TextInput                       0x345d7dee 
KB::DynamicDictionaryImpl::background_load_address_book(KB::StaticDictionary const&) + 194
3   TextInput                       0x345d8728 _ZN2KBL14BackgroundLoadEPv + 272
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3245c72e _pthread_start + 314
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3245c5e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3ea85d98      r6: 0x00000002      r7: 0x2fe80a60
    r8: 0x00000000    r9: 0x00000000     r10: 0x3f330d4c     r11: 0x3f3459c0
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fe80a54      lr: 0x3249b20f      pc: 0x3557532c
  cpsr: 0x00020010
```

Answer (score 2):

Apps are REQUIRED to run on the iPad too even if they target only the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your iOS application target was set to iPhone and not universal?

[image: xcode screenshot]

If you believe all your settings are correct, you can submit an appeal to Apple:

https://developer.apple.com/appstore/contact/appreviewboard/index.html

Comment: Thinking about this a little more - iPhone apps DO need to be able to run as iPhone apps on the iPad, even if they are not designed for iPad.

Answer (score 0):

Do what Lee Crossley said, but also you should go to the Resolution Center in iTunes Connect and tell the reviewer about this. They can reply and fix your problems. They will be better advice than us!